# how to get access to full location path (with external locations) in self write nginx module?

Tags: c, nginx, nginx-location

Hello please help with next issue.
The main question is how to get access to full location path (with external locations) in self write nginx module?

More details:
Want to add remaining path after full location path (with external locations) without '/' (slashes) to ngx_array_t.

There is the following initial data:

nginx.conf
(locations can be changed and module should work correctly)

```
   ...
   location /admin/ {
   directive_name;
   location ~ /internal/ { #no mistake
   directive_name;
   location ~ /internal/ { #no mistake
   directive_name;
   location ~ /internal3/ {
   directive_name;
   location ~ /internal4/ {
   directive_name; }}}}}
   ...
```

uri

```
/admin/internal/internal/internal/one/two/three/
```

Expected array with the following content:

```
   [0] = internal
   [1] = one
   [2] = two
   [3] = three
```

Accordingly in above example full location path (with external locations) is (how to get it?):

```
 /admin/internal/internal/
```

Some thoughts about this question:

1. maybe we can get access through

   ngx_http_core_loc_conf_t *lc = ngx_http_conf_get_module_loc_conf(cf, ngx_http_core_module);
   lc->name; //this is what we need but only part of that, need full location with external locations
2. or maybe we can create a variable in ngx_http_modulename_loc_conf_t and create
   function ngx_http_modulename_merge_loc_conf, but how to write this merge function correctly?

Comment: this question has no relation with c why you add it??

Comment: nginx is written in C language